# activeadmin 0.4.4 crashing on heroku Missing helper file helpers/layout_helper.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm trying to deploy an app on Heroku that works just fine on my PC.  It crashes on heroku with:

**/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:191:in `eval': Missing helper file helpers/layout_helper.rb (LoadError)**

PC details:
Windows 7 x64
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]
Rails 3.2.5

```
$ bundle show
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.2.5)
  * actionpack (3.2.5)
  * activeadmin (0.4.4)
  * activemodel (3.2.5)
  * activerecord (3.2.5)
  * activeresource (3.2.5)
  * activesupport (3.2.5)
  * arel (3.0.2)
  * bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
  * bourbon (2.1.0)
  * builder (3.0.0)
  * bundler (1.1.4)
  * coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
  * devise (2.1.0)
  * diff-lcs (1.1.3)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (1.4.0)
  * faraday (0.8.1)
  * fastercsv (1.5.5)
  * formtastic (2.1.1)
  * has_scope (0.5.1)
  * hashie (1.2.0)
  * hike (1.2.1)
  * httpauth (0.1)
  * i18n (0.6.0)
  * inherited_resources (1.3.1)
  * journey (1.0.3)
  * jquery-rails (2.0.2)
  * json (1.7.3)
  * kaminari (0.13.0)
  * mail (2.4.4)
  * meta_search (1.1.3)
  * mime-types (1.18)
  * multi_json (1.3.6)
  * multipart-post (1.1.5)
  * mysql2 (0.3.11)
  * nifty-generators (0.4.6)
  * oauth (0.4.6)
  * oauth2 (0.6.1)
  * omniauth (1.1.0)
  * omniauth-facebook (1.3.0)
  * omniauth-google-apps (0.0.2)
  * omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
  * omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.2)
  * omniauth-openid (1.0.1)
  * omniauth-twitter (0.0.11)
  * orm_adapter (0.0.7)
  * polyamorous (0.5.0)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * rack (1.4.1)
  * rack-cache (1.2)
  * rack-openid (1.3.1)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.1)
  * rails (3.2.5)
  * rails3_acts_as_paranoid (0.2.4)
  * railties (3.2.5)
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
  * rdoc (3.12)
  * responders (0.9.1)
  * rest-client (1.6.7)
  * rspec (2.10.0)
  * rspec-core (2.10.1)
  * rspec-expectations (2.10.0)
  * rspec-mocks (2.10.1)
  * rspec-rails (2.10.1)
  * ruby-openid (2.1.8)
  * ruby-openid-apps-discovery (1.2.0)
  * sass (3.1.19)
  * sass-rails (3.2.5)
  * spork (1.0.0rc3)
  * spork-rails (3.2.0)
  * sprockets (2.1.3)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.6)
  * stripe (1.7.0)
  * thor (0.15.2)
  * tilt (1.3.3)
  * treetop (1.4.10)
  * tzinfo (0.3.33)
  * uglifier (1.2.4)
  * warden (1.1.1)
```

Full Heroku Error:

```
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from created to starting
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:18+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 50085`
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:39+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle
 them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2
-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:39+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle
 them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2
-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Booting WEBrick
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Rails 3.2.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:50085
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Call with -d to detach
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Exiting
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:191:in `eval': Missing helper file helpers/layout_helper.rb (LoadError
)
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:312:in `depend_on'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:135:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `map!'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `modules_for_helpers'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:92:in `modules_for_helpers'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:95:in `helper'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in with'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/inherited_resources-1.3.1/app/controllers/inherited_resources/base.rb:11:in `<module:InheritedResources>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/inherited_resources-1.3.1/app/controllers/inherited_resources/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/base_controller/menu.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/base_controller/menu.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/base_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/actions.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/actions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/resource_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/dashboards/dashboard_controller.rb:3:in `<module:Dashboards>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/dashboards/dashboard_controller.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/dashboards/dashboard_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from (eval):1:in `generate_dashboard_controller'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:191:in `eval'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:191:in `generate_dashboard_controller'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:43:in `initialize'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:110:in `new'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:110:in `find_or_create_namespace'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:98:in `register'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin.rb:74:in `register'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/app/admin/trades.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:161:in `block in load!'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:161:in `each'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:161:in `load!'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:187:in `routes'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin.rb:78:in `routes'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `reload_routes!'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:34:in `reload!'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:61:in `block in attach!'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run__1844096441965798486__prepare__2735152408631258
258__callbacks'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from script/rails:6:in `require'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:44+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:46+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 1
←[32m2012-06-19T01:01:46+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed
```

Heroku gems installed

```
Installing rake (0.9.2.2)
Installing i18n (0.6.0)
Installing multi_json (1.3.6)
Installing activesupport (3.2.5)
Installing builder (3.0.0)
Installing activemodel (3.2.5)
Installing erubis (2.7.0)
Installing journey (1.0.4)
Installing rack (1.4.1)
Installing rack-cache (1.2)
Installing rack-test (0.6.1)
Installing hike (1.2.1)
Installing tilt (1.3.3)
Installing sprockets (2.1.3)
Installing actionpack (3.2.5)
Installing mime-types (1.18)
Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
Installing treetop (1.4.10)
Installing mail (2.4.4)
Installing actionmailer (3.2.5)
Installing sass (3.1.19)
Installing bourbon (2.1.0)
Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) with native extensions
Installing orm_adapter (0.1.0)
Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2)
Installing json (1.7.3) with native extensions
Installing rdoc (3.12)
Installing thor (0.15.3)
Installing railties (3.2.5)
Installing warden (1.2.1)
Installing devise (2.1.1)
Installing fastercsv (1.5.5)
Installing formtastic (2.1.1)
Installing has_scope (0.5.1)
Installing responders (0.9.1)
Installing inherited_resources (1.3.1)
Installing jquery-rails (2.0.2)
Installing kaminari (0.13.0)
Installing arel (3.0.2)
Installing tzinfo (0.3.33)
Installing activerecord (3.2.5)
Installing polyamorous (0.5.0)
Installing meta_search (1.1.3)
Installing activeresource (3.2.5)
Using bundler (1.2.0.pre)
Installing rails (3.2.5)
Installing activeadmin (0.4.4)
Installing coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
Installing execjs (1.4.0)
Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Installing multipart-post (1.1.5)
Installing faraday (0.8.1)
Installing hashie (1.2.0)
Installing httpauth (0.1)
Installing mysql2 (0.3.11) with native extensions
Installing oauth (0.4.6)
Installing oauth2 (0.6.1)
Installing omniauth (1.1.0)
Installing omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.2)
Installing omniauth-facebook (1.3.0)
Installing ruby-openid (2.1.8)
Installing rack-openid (1.3.1)
Installing omniauth-openid (1.0.1)
Installing ruby-openid-apps-discovery (1.2.0)
Installing omniauth-google-apps (0.0.2)
Installing omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
Installing omniauth-twitter (0.0.11)
Installing rails3_acts_as_paranoid (0.2.4)
Installing rest-client (1.6.7)
Installing sass-rails (3.2.5)
Installing stripe (1.7.0)
Installing uglifier (1.2.4)
```

I'm running the **cedar stack** on Heroku, **version** command reports **2.27.3**.

My Apps Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'meta_search'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'mysql2'


gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-google-apps'
gem 'omniauth-openid'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'ruby-openid'

gem 'devise'

gem 'formtastic'

gem 'inherited_resources'

gem 'rails3_acts_as_paranoid'

gem 'stripe'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'spork-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'nifty-generators'
end
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ git ls-files 
.gitignore 
.idea/.generators 
.idea/.name 
.idea/.rakeTasks 
.idea/dataSources.ids 
.idea/dataSources.xml 
.idea/dictionaries/Desktop.xml 
.idea/encodings.xml 
.idea/misc.xml 
.idea/modules.xml 
.idea/scopes/scope_settings.xml 
.idea/travelingnuker-com.iml 
.idea/vcs.xml 
.idea/workspace.xml 
.rspec 
Gemfile 
Gemfile.lock 
README.rdoc 
Rakefile 
app/admin/admin_users.rb 
app/admin/dashboards.rb 
app/admin/outages.rb 
app/admin/plants.rb 
app/admin/services.rb 
app/admin/states.rb 
app/admin/trades.rb 
app/admin/unemployment_infos.rb 
app/admin/unions.rb 
app/admin/unit_aliases.rb 
app/admin/units.rb 
app/admin/users.rb 
app/assets/images/Aol_32.png 
app/assets/images/Facebook_32.png 
app/assets/images/Google_32.png 
app/assets/images/Myspace_32.png 
app/assets/images/Openid_32.png 
app/assets/images/Traveling-Nuker-Logo-Small.png 
app/assets/images/Traveling-Nuker-Logo-Wide.png 
app/assets/images/Twitter_32.png 
app/assets/images/Yahoo_32.png 
app/assets/images/backstripes.gif 
app/assets/images/bg_header.jpg 
app/assets/images/bullet1.gif 
app/assets/images/bullet2.gif 
app/assets/images/cal-grey.gif 
app/assets/images/cal.gif 
app/assets/images/chris-baran.png 
app/assets/images/cvv.gif 
app/assets/images/favicon.ico 
app/assets/images/gradient-e5e5e5-ffffff.gif 
app/assets/images/help.jpg 
app/assets/images/rails.png 
app/assets/images/unionlogos/hfiaw.gif 
app/assets/images/unionlogos/ibb.jpg 
app/assets/images/unionlogos/ibew.jpg 
app/assets/images/unionlogos/ironworkers.jpg 
app/assets/images/unionlogos/iuoe.jpg 
app/assets/images/unionlogos/iupat.jpg 
app/assets/images/unionlogos/liuna.jpg 
app/assets/images/unionlogos/smwia.png 
app/assets/images/unionlogos/ua.png 
app/assets/images/unionlogos/ubc.png 
app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js 
app/assets/javascripts/application.js 
app/assets/javascripts/authentications.js.coffee 
app/assets/javascripts/home.js.coffee 
app/assets/javascripts/outage_lists.js.coffee 
app/assets/javascripts/page.js.coffee 
app/assets/javascripts/registrations.js.coffee 
app/assets/javascripts/users.js.coffee 
app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss 
app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss 
app/assets/stylesheets/authentications.css.scss 
app/assets/stylesheets/blueprint/blueprint.css.scss 
app/assets/stylesheets/blueprint/forms.css 
app/assets/stylesheets/blueprint/grid.css 
app/assets/stylesheets/blueprint/grid.png 
app/assets/stylesheets/blueprint/ie.css 
app/assets/stylesheets/blueprint/reset.css 
app/assets/stylesheets/blueprint/typography.css 
app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss 
app/assets/stylesheets/home.css.scss 
app/assets/stylesheets/outage_lists.css.scss 
app/assets/stylesheets/page.css.scss 
app/assets/stylesheets/registrations.css.scss 
app/assets/stylesheets/users.css.scss 
app/controllers/application_controller.rb 
app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb 
app/controllers/outage_lists_controller.rb 
app/controllers/pages_controller.rb 
app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb 
app/controllers/users_controller.rb 
app/helpers/Layout_helper.rb 
app/helpers/application_helper.rb 
app/helpers/authentications_helper.rb 
app/helpers/home_helper.rb 
app/helpers/outage_lists_helper.rb 
app/helpers/pages_helper.rb 
app/helpers/registrations_helper.rb 
app/helpers/users_helper.rb 
app/mailers/.gitkeep 
app/models/.gitkeep 
app/models/admin_user.rb 
app/models/authentication.rb 
app/models/contractor.rb 
app/models/contractor_contract.rb 
app/models/difference.rb 
app/models/outage.rb 
app/models/plant.rb 
app/models/service.rb 
app/models/state.rb 
app/models/subscription.rb 
app/models/subscription_affiliate.rb 
app/models/subscription_discount.rb 
app/models/subscription_notifier.rb 
app/models/subscription_payment.rb 
app/models/subscription_plan.rb 
app/models/subscription_plan_feature.rb 
app/models/subscription_plan_feature_list.rb 
app/models/trade.rb 
app/models/unemployment_info.rb 
app/models/union.rb 
app/models/unit.rb 
app/models/unit_alias.rb 
app/models/unit_status.rb 
app/models/user.rb 
app/views/devise/confirmations/new.html.erb 
app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb 
app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb 
app/views/devise/mailer/unlock_instructions.html.erb 
app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb 
app/views/devise/passwords/new.html.erb 
app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb 
app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb 
app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb 
app/views/devise/shared/_links.erb 
app/views/devise/unlocks/new.html.erb 
app/views/layouts/_footer.html.erb 
app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb 
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb 
app/views/outage_lists/index.html.erb 
app/views/pages/about_us.html.erb 
app/views/pages/help.html.erb 
app/views/pages/index.html.erb 
app/views/pages/nukeworker_faq.html.erb 
app/views/pages/plans.html.erb 
app/views/pages/tos.html.erb 
app/views/registrations/edit.html.erb 
app/views/registrations/new.html.erb 
app/views/subscription_notifier/charge_failure.html.erb 
app/views/subscription_notifier/charge_receipt.html.erb 
app/views/subscription_notifier/misc_receipt.html.erb 
app/views/subscription_notifier/plan_changed.html.erb 
app/views/subscription_notifier/setup_receipt.html.erb 
app/views/subscription_notifier/trial_expiring.html.erb 
app/views/users/dashboard.html.erb 
app/views/users/delete_account.html.erb 
config.ru 
config/application.rb 
config/boot.rb 
config/database.yml 
config/environment.rb 
config/environments/development.rb 
config/environments/production.rb 
config/environments/test.rb 
config/initializers/actionmailer.rb 
config/initializers/active_admin.rb 
config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb 
config/initializers/devise.rb 
config/initializers/formtastic.rb 
config/initializers/inflections.rb 
config/initializers/mime_types.rb 
config/initializers/secret_token.rb 
config/initializers/session_store.rb 
config/initializers/stripe.rb 
config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb 
config/locales/devise.en.yml 
config/locales/en.yml 
config/routes.rb 
db/data/Seed 6-14-12.sql 
db/data/normalize_data.rb 
db/migrate/20120603175306_devise_create_users.rb 
db/migrate/20120603182040_customize_users.rb 
db/migrate/20120611172251_create_admin_notes.rb 
db/migrate/20120611172252_move_admin_notes_to_comments.rb 
db/migrate/20120611212211_devise_create_admin_users.rb 
db/migrate/20120611221508_create_outages.rb 
db/migrate/20120613214419_create_units.rb 
db/migrate/20120614152419_create_plants.rb 
db/migrate/20120614153853_create_services.rb 
db/migrate/20120614154222_create_states.rb 
db/migrate/20120614161132_create_trades.rb 
db/migrate/20120614165118_create_unemployment_infos.rb 
db/migrate/20120614205708_create_unions.rb 
db/migrate/20120614210051_create_unit_aliases.rb 
db/migrate/20120614210402_create_unit_statuses.rb 
db/migrate/20120614211227_create_authentications.rb 
db/migrate/20120614213331_create_differences.rb 
db/migrate/20120615000650_create_contractors.rb 
db/migrate/20120615001258_create_contractor_contracts.rb 
db/migrate/20120619033658_create_subscriptions.rb 
db/migrate/20120619041017_create_subscription_plans.rb 
db/migrate/20120619043549_create_subscription_plan_feature_lists.rb 
db/migrate/20120619044617_create_subscription_plan_features.rb 
db/migrate/20120619051802_create_subscription_payments.rb 
db/migrate/20120619072027_create_subscription_affiliates.rb 
db/migrate/20120619083424_create_subscription_discounts.rb 
db/schema.rb 
db/seeds.rb 
doc/README_FOR_APP 
lib/assets/.gitkeep 
lib/tasks/.gitkeep 
lib/templates/erb/scaffold/_form.html.erb 
log/.gitkeep 
public/404.html 
public/422.html 
public/500.html 
public/assets/Aol_32-1a6c49c34132684c4c424e6014a1460b.png 
public/assets/Aol_32.png 
public/assets/Facebook_32-56cd78cb046f8c110edbea8580a52c39.png 
public/assets/Facebook_32.png 
public/assets/Google_32-31dd8ed4ed8218ffb86813de859f1825.png 
public/assets/Google_32.png 
public/assets/Myspace_32-04ef7a4ea01d3ac863adc6e7c27fc145.png 
public/assets/Myspace_32.png 
public/assets/Openid_32-0010c4d031958a273ed9339d4b6fe996.png 
public/assets/Openid_32.png 
public/assets/Traveling-Nuker-Logo-Small-6e97a922e907b1d29aa0252a39f0e9c4.png 
public/assets/Traveling-Nuker-Logo-Small.png 
public/assets/Traveling-Nuker-Logo-Wide-d36b29a77ba0e0afa34f7daa4c37ef83.png 
public/assets/Traveling-Nuker-Logo-Wide.png 
public/assets/Twitter_32-d5ad07c40b2b038c8c99917c720060ed.png 
public/assets/Twitter_32.png 
public/assets/Yahoo_32-6f27c922bb27c3558554bb263bed5040.png 
public/assets/Yahoo_32.png 
public/assets/active_admin-8106e85ad95955c15013ac8969ec2482.js 
public/assets/active_admin-8106e85ad95955c15013ac8969ec2482.js.gz 
public/assets/active_admin-f55a970cc8f92d42a0dc76037952528d.css 
public/assets/active_admin-f55a970cc8f92d42a0dc76037952528d.css.gz 
public/assets/active_admin.css 
public/assets/active_admin.css.gz 
public/assets/active_admin.js 
public/assets/active_admin.js.gz 
public/assets/active_admin/admin_notes_icon-04bd616ed9d1ff51d7a53422d4caf510.png 
public/assets/active_admin/admin_notes_icon.png 
public/assets/active_admin/application-07fb877e0a0431c839801f158020b702.js 
public/assets/active_admin/application-07fb877e0a0431c839801f158020b702.js.gz 
public/assets/active_admin/application.js 
public/assets/active_admin/application.js.gz 
public/assets/active_admin/datepicker/datepicker-header-bg-5f452fde9ca93c1fe7e9d47f0a3ece6a.png 
public/assets/active_admin/datepicker/datepicker-header-bg.png 
public/assets/active_admin/datepicker/datepicker-input-icon-876ae70b38bc880f91ce2315ed552260.png 
public/assets/active_admin/datepicker/datepicker-input-icon.png 
public/assets/active_admin/datepicker/datepicker-next-link-icon-23a49449514d929cfc8c5c9b7c510d3b.png 
public/assets/active_admin/datepicker/datepicker-next-link-icon.png 
public/assets/active_admin/datepicker/datepicker-nipple-e13362aa148d84973a266eeee0b89e9a.png 
public/assets/active_admin/datepicker/datepicker-nipple.png 
public/assets/active_admin/datepicker/datepicker-prev-link-icon-43d0f297400cd14812abc8f7c6705d17.png 
public/assets/active_admin/datepicker/datepicker-prev-link-icon.png 
public/assets/active_admin/loading-38b99f1fc3078c0d0403fdf80e22f896.gif 
public/assets/active_admin/loading.gif 
public/assets/active_admin/nested_menu_arrow-dcb32755d9740e23965a1e76bb945ce9.gif 
public/assets/active_admin/nested_menu_arrow.gif 
public/assets/active_admin/nested_menu_arrow_dark-f9fe6b6a563b7b15f3cd1be4e98d1ce0.gif 
public/assets/active_admin/nested_menu_arrow_dark.gif 
public/assets/active_admin/orderable-d9e1503253eff94adee978d6f43f2409.png 
public/assets/active_admin/orderable.png 
public/assets/application-0238dd46e6f519804b2702287114d150.js 
public/assets/application-0238dd46e6f519804b2702287114d150.js.gz 
public/assets/application-3ec33221355ebfa321663ecbe4ac767f.css 
public/assets/application-3ec33221355ebfa321663ecbe4ac767f.css.gz 
public/assets/application.css 
public/assets/application.css.gz 
public/assets/application.js 
public/assets/application.js.gz 
public/assets/backstripes-0fab8c43ff641c785ef54fdce999b42f.gif 
public/assets/backstripes.gif 
public/assets/bg_header-c6f8f39be5373f0f4ac16adbf535390f.jpg 
public/assets/bg_header.jpg 
public/assets/blueprint/grid-99a56fe9528f46c2bbb7084a7e34bb4f.png 
public/assets/blueprint/grid.png 
public/assets/bullet1-064f37cf76389c03e6bf30b9b4cbc9c1.gif 
public/assets/bullet1.gif 
public/assets/bullet2-515ae1d51ee13f93f1839d278b1253fb.gif 
public/assets/bullet2.gif 
public/assets/cal-ae0f4c6add16d31a81762a8a956810fc.gif 
public/assets/cal-grey-5f974f544088835b3e8066179d2156cb.gif 
public/assets/cal-grey.gif 
public/assets/cal.gif 
public/assets/chris-baran-adc4f56c4dfe73e5ef9b87dde6902c43.png 
public/assets/chris-baran.png 
public/assets/cvv-1e754aa113fa03851d88a2ba5c14f5a5.gif 
public/assets/cvv.gif 
public/assets/favicon-c6c841693b043edd73baffbd217cf86e.ico 
public/assets/favicon.ico 
public/assets/gradient-e5e5e5-ffffff-13165a4881bd9eeeb323550641b28347.gif 
public/assets/gradient-e5e5e5-ffffff.gif 
public/assets/help-96b5cb035a19b7ccf2ffd7f2f57f74c4.jpg 
public/assets/help.jpg 
public/assets/manifest.yml 
public/assets/rails-be8732dac73d845ac5b142c8fb5f9fb0.png 
public/assets/rails.png 
public/assets/unionlogos/hfiaw-ef9657096f75e427d994b86385fb4a53.gif 
public/assets/unionlogos/hfiaw.gif 
public/assets/unionlogos/ibb-2df808fa1ee6ec0fafe1bd9e88e04916.jpg 
public/assets/unionlogos/ibb.jpg 
public/assets/unionlogos/ibew-8d7c2d6d987dc77e978bf1105fb9dadd.jpg 
public/assets/unionlogos/ibew.jpg 
public/assets/unionlogos/ironworkers-1f1aeca4387f15a1630822ee7c7a553c.jpg 
public/assets/unionlogos/ironworkers.jpg 
public/assets/unionlogos/iuoe-d69f45647c3e15a89cb3c7fa2acbb892.jpg 
public/assets/unionlogos/iuoe.jpg 
public/assets/unionlogos/iupat-12eb9dc83b3b7d9c4de967202118d4e8.jpg 
public/assets/unionlogos/iupat.jpg 
public/assets/unionlogos/liuna-418a82dd5fcb244c1936d7cf4f39caa0.jpg 
public/assets/unionlogos/liuna.jpg 
public/assets/unionlogos/smwia-3531293f003837e5a7b5bd8c473ea3cb.png 
public/assets/unionlogos/smwia.png 
public/assets/unionlogos/ua-14c86465eca7a1ec0974cee962def380.png 
public/assets/unionlogos/ua.png 
public/assets/unionlogos/ubc-147f9f91c17ad3d5bbcf6d0fd4774696.png 
public/assets/unionlogos/ubc.png 
public/favicon.ico 
public/robots.txt 
script/rails 
spec/controllers/authentications_controller_spec.rb 
spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb 
spec/controllers/outage_lists_controller_spec.rb 
spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb 
spec/controllers/registrations_controller_spec.rb 
spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb 
spec/helpers/authentications_helper_spec.rb 
spec/helpers/home_helper_spec.rb 
spec/helpers/outage_lists_helper_spec.rb 
spec/helpers/pages_helper_spec.rb 
spec/helpers/registrations_helper_spec.rb 
spec/helpers/users_helper_spec.rb 
spec/models/authentication_spec.rb 
spec/models/contractor_contract_spec.rb 
spec/models/contractor_spec.rb 
spec/models/difference_spec.rb 
spec/models/plant_spec.rb 
spec/models/service_spec.rb 
spec/models/state_spec.rb 
spec/models/subscription_affiliates_spec.rb 
spec/models/subscription_discount_spec.rb 
spec/models/subscription_payments_spec.rb 
spec/models/subscription_plan_feature_list_spec.rb 
spec/models/subscription_plan_feature_spec.rb 
spec/models/subscription_plan_features_spec.rb 
spec/models/subscription_plan_spec.rb 
spec/models/subscriptions_spec.rb 
spec/models/trade_spec.rb 
spec/models/unemployment_info_spec.rb 
spec/models/unions_spec.rb 
spec/models/unit_alias_spec.rb 
spec/models/unit_status_spec.rb 
spec/spec_helper.rb 
test/fixtures/.gitkeep 
test/fixtures/admin_users.yml 
test/fixtures/outages.yml 
test/fixtures/units.yml 
test/fixtures/users.yml 
test/functional/.gitkeep 
test/integration/.gitkeep 
test/performance/browsing_test.rb 
test/test_helper.rb 
test/unit/.gitkeep 
test/unit/admin_user_test.rb 
test/unit/outage_test.rb 
test/unit/unit_test.rb 
test/unit/user_test.rb
```

This problem was caused by the fact that my Layout_helper.rb file had a capital "L" in it's filename.  Very strange considering I created this project on windows.  It does explain why I could run this app on Windows with no problem.  I had to check this out on a linux system, change the filename to have a lowercase "L" and commit it back.  Then it was fine and launched perfectly!